# how to replace an existing tab item with a new tab

Tags: android

I'm developing a android tab based application, i need to know how to replace an existing tab item with a new tab.

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove tab dynamically try it...

```
// data structure, what I referred to as memory
ArrayList<TabHost.TabSpec> list = new ArrayList<TabHost.TabSpec>();

// when you are adding tabs to tab host
// what you add, you remember
TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabs.newTabSpec("tag1");
spec.setContent(R.id.button);
spec.setIndicator("TabONe");
tabs.addTab(spec);
list.add(spec);
 ...
// when you want to remove
list.remove(list.size()-1); // remove it from memory
//set here current tab position
tabs.clearAllTabs(); // clear all tabs from the tabhost
for(TabHost.TabSpec spec : list) // add all that you remember back
tabs.addTab(spec);
```

To add this by another at the same position add your new TabSpec..

Comment: This  worked for me but when the tab changed tab is moved from left to right, i'm checking on samsung Nexsus S phone...

Comment: hey in above eg I have removed the last tab. You can also remove any tab in between and add a new at that position.like:
list.remove(2);
list.set(2,spec);
and then apply the foreach loop for adding tab.